# Is there any API(or sdk method) which checks whether document visibility setting under SIGNING_SETTING option of docusign admin account is ON/OFF?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm not able to find an API or a SDK method which can tell me whether document visibility option in the [SIGNING_SETTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNrat.png) of docusign admin account is ON/OFF.
Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Accounts:listSettings](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/listsettings/)

If it doesn't work, please post your API call log. See [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging)